# Deleting variables in Airflow DAG: What's the best way to do it?

Tags: airflow

I am creating some variables in Airflow DAG. I want to delete those variables in another Airflow DAG at a later point of time (after 15 days or so). Could someone let me know how do we delete airflow variables through DAG. I am basically looking for the command like we use to create or set the variable (Variable.get, Variable.set). I am new to Python & Airflow. Thanks in advance.

I have tried deleting the variable using in python callable function:

global my_var

del my_var

I have also tried Variable.delete(my_var)

But both throw the same error: NameError: name 'my_var' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You can use airflow cli

`airflow variables delete <VARIABLE_NAME>`

and this can be a task in other DAG maybe a bash operator

```
delete_variable_task = BashOperator(
         task_id="delete_variable",
         bash_command="airflow variables delete <VARIABLE_NAME>",
)
```

Airflow CLI docs: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#variables